# Why does my sprite kit game have extra space off to the side of my visible scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I manually set the size of my scene to 768 x 1024 but for some reason can only see around 500 pixels of my 768. The other 260 something pixels are to the right, and left of the scene off screen. How can I find out:

1) Why this happens

2) Exactly how many pixels are to either side

This extra space is making it really hard for me to place sprite nodes correctly!

Here is my viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        scene.size = CGSizeMake(768, 1024)
        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha woops. Just noticed this is not a Cocos2d question.

Comment: Are you in landscape or portrait orientation when you are seeing the extra space? 260 is juuuust about 1024 - 768 which leads me to think your SKView is being added without proper constraints or auto-resizing mask.

Comment: Try setting the scaleMode to .ResizeFill and check that your sis file does not have a different value for the size.